# Having android gradle open windows cmd and run a command after build done?

Tags: android, gradle, cmd

I'm building an android module with this standard build script:

```
buildscript {// top-level    
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've googled a lot to know how to have gradle to open windos cmd (I'm on win7) and run a command. I found tasks Exec and added, but it didn't work for me, perhaps I don't still understand groovy and gradle. Please make me clear how to do it.

**Edit**
By using a forum post mentioned in comments, I added this to android{..} section:

```
    task testingit(type:Exec) {
      println('try open cmd...............')
      commandLine "cmd","/k",'node', '-v'
    }
```

I get the string output but cmd does not open and no error message.

Comment: Is there anything in this question/answer that helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315287/how-to-execute-a-command-in-windows-cmd-using-gradle

Comment: Thank you, exactly it's that one I mentioned above, I added that after my task clean, but it does not open cmd. I don't  understand what I'm doing wrong. Could you provide a simple example that works, just simply to open cmd at post-build please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute this task at the end of build, you can use `build.finalizedBy`.

```
task endBuildTask(type: Exec) {
   commandLine  'cmd','/c','start', 'cmd.exe' ,'@cmd' , '/k', 'echo', 'Hello'
}
build.finalizedBy(endBuildTask)
// or gradle.buildFinished{endBuildTask.execute()}
```

This will create a new command line at the end of build, pass the command after @cmd to the newly created command line. If you want this new command line to close after command executes, use '/c' instead of '/k'.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I still don't get something there, I added exactly this code after "clean" task in project script and I get the error "Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project...", next added it after my dependencies {...} in my module script, I get the build success but cmd does not open. I added printLN to test, and the string is on output, so the task is read, but for unknown reason to me still doesnt work. How to get it to work please?

Comment: Also, when I add an output string to this task, I get the string at the begining, i.e. right after "Executing tasks: [...]", but I expect it to come at the end, because of finalizedBy, maybe by thins you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: @AdrianDain I suggest you to, start a simple project and make your way up to the your current setup.(like First try opening a cmd at the end of build in the simple project). I can confirm that this will create a cmd at the end of build.

Comment: @AdrianDain If you want this to execute after a certain task, lets say taskX, you can add the following to assure this `endBuildTask.dependsOn taskX`

Comment: I exactly did as you instructed. I started a simple project, with basic activity, then in build script of Module: app, I added this code once at the end of android {...} as the last property, rebuilt the project (and no result), and next after dependencies {...} and rebuilt. In both cases I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL, and I get my test string output at the start of the build, but no cmd opens! Please, what I'm misunderstanding or not understanding here? Stocked for quite a while now! Thanks you.

Comment: About taskX, I have no task defines, I want to simply open this cmd in the simple project as you suggested and I can't get it done and no way I can understand why!

Comment: @AdrianDain Can you upload this simple project to somewhere, so I can try it.

Comment: @AdrianDain try this `gradle.buildFinished{endBuildTask.execute()}`.  I dont have android build enviroment, I cant test it if this will work for android project. but for java project this is working when project is built with gradle build command

Comment: Many thanks, I rebuilt  my original project by your last suggestion and it worked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166569/discussion-between-adrian-dain-and-miroh).

Answer (score 1):

I just post back how I put the accepted answer from above in my application, in case useful for anyone (because build.finalizedBy(endBuildTask) didn't work and I can't understand why, but gradle.buildFinished(...) did the job)
This is how I got it working:

```
task endBuildTask(type: Exec) {
  workingDir 'C:\\tmp\\1\\'
  commandLine  'cmd','/c','node', '%FILE_JS%'
}

gradle.buildFinished{
    endBuildTask.execute()
}
```

I had a nodejs app that I wanted to execute after android build is over.